# Fast Report fr3 File loading Error in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, fastreport

I have question about loading *.fr3 in DelphiXE5,
I designed a report and pointed some text to Memo inside of Fast Report everything was ok until I want to load fast Report file from out site App it works for my PC perfectly but when I install client side it gets Error like this Photo include in this message
And the code I used is:

```
begin
frxReport1.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'R1.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport();
frxReport1.ShowReport();
end;
```

Error message:

```
'18/89765' is not a valid floatin point value
'238/11039' is not a valid floatin point value
'275/90569' is not a valid floatin point value
'41984/5614698264' is not a valid floatin point value
'41984/5618072454' is not a valid floatin point value
'94/48825' is not a valid floatin point value
```

Comment: what kind of error you get?

Comment: Don't try to include an image of the error. Include the **exact error message** in your question as text. There's no need for a graphic. Just [edit] your question and add the error message.

Comment: Who on earth stores floating point values with `/` slash as a decimal separator ? As it looks like the reporting engine is trying to convert such string values to floating point but cannot due to this decimal separator.

Comment: i just make a empty report without any text and save as fr3 near app.exe and try to load this report when app is running it can load in my Computer but it can't load on other Computers why ? !!!! it gets Error the same !!!!!

Comment: i testing in my own Computer and virtual windows i testes in two Windows, Windows7 and WindowsXP and i also use inf and loading image File its work perfectly i know i have Windows permission

Comment: Curious that "floating" is misspelt. Anyway, it doesn't sound like readers could diagnose this problem from here. Write a test app that writes and reads a file in the same location on the other computers as your report - does that work? Does FC.Exe find any differences between your report and app on your computer and the others?  Btw, .FR3 files are just XML files with an encoding of UTF-8.  Try opening one of them on one of the other computers in Notepad: does it look ok?

Comment: I couldn't find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the problem was Microsoft windows 8.1 
I'm using Microsoft Windows 8.1, Delphi Xe 5 and Fast-report 4.15.6
First I made a report in fast report without any change and then run my app in windows 7 save as Fast-report to file and then use in all version of Microsoft Windows,  thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been originated form Regional Settings.
Win 8.1 automatically changes decimal separator as '.' to '/' in Persian language, even in fast reports.
The Microsoft has to figure this problem out.

Answer (score -1):

step 1: open frxutils.pas from fastreport lib

step 2: function frxStrToFloat(s: String): Extended;

step 3: relapse this code: [',', '.']) with [',', '.','/']